# DLL compiled in Windows 8 doesn't work in Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I got a program that use a .dll compiled on Windows 8. When I move the program and its .dll to Windows 7, the program crashes. It must be because of DLL compilation configuration I guess.

Below is part of the header file of the .dll

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    void myFunc(void);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

I tried Dependency Walker but dont understand it. In Windows 8, the dll has some missing dependencies but working well. In Windows 7, the dll missing dependencies is different

The program is compiled using TDM MinGW (it has to) while the DLL is compiled using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: Compile using `-static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Make error line 304: problem compiling: mingw32-g++: error: unrecognized option '-static-libstdc++'

Comment: Can you be more precise abut the nature of the "crash"?  What error messages are reported for example?  Did it truly crash or just abort on failure to load or link the library?

Comment: @Clifford The program runs fine until it calls to load the DLL then it crashes. the error is: MyProgram encountered an internal error and will now close. It only happens in Windows 7, but runs fine in Windows 8

Comment: It seems to me that you  are blaming the DLL but the problem is highly likely to be elsewhere.  I am not sure that posting the header file code is especially helpful; the code that is actually failing may be a better bet.

Comment: @Clifford thanks for the input. i finally figured it out. called function in DLL cannot allocate memory and pass char* to caller (main program). instead, caller (in main program) must allocate the memory (new char[size]) and let the called function return char*. else windows won't let the program run.

Comment: @mnaim86:  That is useful information - you should add it as an answer rather than a comment perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Small wonder. Changes in the C++ language tend to force ABI differences (libraries aren't compatible anymore). And the operating systems are also (somewhat) different...

Answer (score 1):

The name mangling process C++ uses to support class membership and function overloading differs between compilers.  It is never guaranteed (and is in fact unlikely) that C++ symbols in a DLL written in one compiler will match the symbols generated in a different compiler.

See [this on name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Standardised_name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) for details. Ultimately whatever the actual cause of the crash, the use of different compilers for the DLL and application code is probably unsafe.

You need either to use the same compiler throughout, or provide a DLL API with C linkage.

Comment: In this case I cant use the same compiler. Will try the DLL API with C linkage. Thanks

Comment: @mnaim86:  My error, your header file shows that you are already using  C linkage (that's what the `extern "C"` is for).